# Mod function returns 0 for Matlab

Tags: matlab, elliptic-curve

I have a problem with the `mod` function output in Matlab. I am trying to perform some calculations for ECC double and add algorithm. I am reading data from a file and storing it in a variable and then performing some operations. All works smoothly except that I get `0` in `temp1` when I use `mod(X2,P)`. However if I put in values stored in `X2(3.0323e+153)` and `P(1.1579e+77)` on command window (`mod( 3.0323e+153, 1.1579e+77)`), I get the correct values. Can anyone please help me? Below is the part of script which is problematic.

```
P = hex2dec('FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F');
line = fread(fileID,[1,67],'*char');
while ~feof(fileID)
        PX = line(4:67);
        X = hex2dec(PX);
        X2 = X^2;
        temp1= mod(X2 , P)
    end
    line = fread(fileID,[1,69],'*char');
end
fclose(fileID);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies with how you're initializing `P`. From the documentation for [`hex2dec`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hex2dec.html) (emphasis mine):

> `d = hex2dec('hex_value')` converts *hex_value* to its floating-point integer representation. The argument *hex_value* is a hexadecimal integer stored as text. **If the value of *hex_value* is greater than the hexadecimal equivalent of the value returned by `flintmax`, then `hex2dec` might not return an exact conversion.**

And the value of [`flintmax`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flintmax.html) is:

```
>> flintmax
ans =
     9.007199254740992e+15
```

Quite a bit smaller than your value for `P`. In fact, if we use [`num2hex`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2hex.html) to look at the two ways you initialize `P`, you can see a clear difference:

```
>> P = hex2dec('FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F');
>> num2hex(P)
ans =
4ff0000000000000
>> num2hex(1.1579e+77)
ans =
4fefffda293c30de
```

As it turns out, the inexact conversion done by `hex2dec` results in a number that evenly divides into `3.0323e+153`, thus giving you a remainder of 0:

```
>> mod(3.0323e+153, P)
ans =
     0
>> mod(3.0323e+153, 1.1579e+77)
ans =
     8.795697942083107e+76
```

Comment: Yes that is the problem so Matlab cannot handle 256 bit number arithmetic. Do you know any library or add on which can work with MATLAB for 256 bit arithmetic?

Comment: @Eshaal: Perhaps [`vpa`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) from the Symbolic Math Toolbox?